# iOS 9 occasional black screen when waking up an application from sleep

Tags: swift, crash, ios9, sleep, wakeup

I have a complex application that when it has been asleep for while and it is relauched shows a complete backscreen.

It's very difficult to reproduce this (I haven't managed with the simulator).

My question is simple I would be the best way of troubleshooting this and what could be the cause of this issue.

I'm using the AsyncDisplayKit framework heavily (this might cause something). I'm developping for iOS9 in Swift.

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you see this in the simulator on a real device, if device, what device?

Comment: on iPhone 6 and 6s for sure but probably the other ones. I can see facebook app has the same issue of black screen but after a few seconds it manages to recover